# Stuck at integrating payments and redirections on a WordPress website

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress website and finding myself stuck at a point. I have made several e-commerce sites and blogs but haven't really made this type of website.

This is an educational website. I'd like to know how can I implement the following workflow.

1- Someone comes and registers themself.

2- Pays a specific amount.

3- After the confirmation of the amount, he will be redirected to all the resources.

I'm actually done with the registration process, now I'd like to know how can I do the /2 and /3.
If there are any free or paid plugin which offers this workflow, please mention.

Comment: You can use the free members plugin ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gravity forms (https://docs.gravityforms.com) to display the payment options. This can be used along with a customizable payment plugin (preferably with Gravity Forms integration) that will allow redirection to the required resources on payment confirmation, similar to [this plugin](https://www.novalnet.com/modul/gravity-forms) offered by Novalnet.